# rotate image with android sprite

Tags: android, sprite

I am building a virtual store with the effect same like this

[enter link description here](http://www.htc.com/au/smartphones/)

The user can freely rotate the image from left to right and top to bottom or vice versa. I suppose to use sprite 2D to implement that animation. There are some tutorials I found but because Im pretty new about graphic programming so could anyone point me to the correct way that approach my expected performance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2D, you'll need to have a set of images which shows the product from different angles. I suggest you to do some 3D modelling, and render each frame to a sprite sheet.

However, this method is not memory-cheap. But I think it's the most efficient way.

Found this on Google as an example: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/zBSMnjLUDehX2xqqJwLb4wB6Ls4QMExlhum69K48fTNxPf71CJoYBg28DeAvNEYrQkkUdqRJAShD16BXVEXbfNoq9SBF9yINe5-nmQd8a3fGnt9KaJI

Comment: That depends on which application would you like to use for modelling. I suggest you Blender, which is an open-source, therefore free alternative. 

Tutorial for Blender: http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/
Download Blender: http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/